# TXTextControl .NET - Localization and satellite assembly installation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0, txtextcontrol

**Tx Text Control USER INTERFACE TRANSLATION**

I am trying to understand how to build a satellite assembly but I am not really grasping the idea of how to begin.

So far, I have been running the project in my localhost and I was able to execute and get it running as a demo. I had to link the `.dll` files from my application's installation folder to my .NET 6 MVC project.

Here are some links that guide you through the creation of a satellite assembly for changing the language of the user interface to a language of your preference.

**Using the Resource Kit**

[https://docs.textcontrol.com/textcontrol/windows-forms/article.techarticle.resourcekit.htm][1]

**Create satellite assemblies for .NET apps**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/create-satellite-assemblies

**EDIT**

The version of the web application is .NET 6 and I am debugging the ASP.NET Core > tx-aspnet-core-editor sample.
I had to register this key `txtextcontrol.resources,6B83FE9A75CFB638` to my System Registry.

The path is this:
`MyComputer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification\txtextcontrol.resources,6B83FE9A75CFB638`.

Firstly, I have tried doing some of the translations on the `.resx` files which are located here => `C:\Program Files\Text Control GmbH\TX Text Control 32.0.NET Server for ASP.NET\ResourceKit`

I executed the `buildres.bat` - running the command `buildres es` file which firstly generated the resource files and then the dll files: `TXTextControl.resources.dll, TXTextControl.Web.Server.Process.resources.dll`

After this, I have put the .dll files into a subdirectory of my software application located here: `C:\Program Files\Text Control GmbH\TX Text Control 32.0.NET Server for ASP.NET\Assembly\es`.

Finally I have tried debugging my .NET Core application by setting as a default language the Spanish language:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES");
```

The language still remains in English. Is there any suggestion on how to be able to translate this efficiently? Is there maybe a demo of another language besides German and English ?

I have tried the German .dll version and it works.
Just for testing, I copied the german assembly files to the `/es` subdirectory so that I can see that the translation is working but it does not.

Can anyone give me a hint on what I need for making this possible ?

Thanks

Comment: is that a [tag:winform] or [tag:asp.net-mvc]? by the link for textcontrol, it is a winform..

Comment: It is asp.net-mvc. I don't think the interface changes whether you are executing it as a windows application or in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution after a week of doing a thorough research on the matter.

I firstly generated the .dll files which contain all the translations.
To achieve that I had to firstly go to `C:\Program Files\Text Control GmbH\TX Text Control 32.0.NET Server for ASP.NET\ResourceKit`

and opened the `buildres.bat` file.
I had to do some minor edits to that file which were these:
For the spanish language you neet to specify the ISO code for spanish language which is `buildres es` just at the last line of the script.

```
@if "%1"=="" goto error
@echo generating resources files:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\ResGen.exe" textcontrol.resx TXTextControl.TextControlCore.%1.resources
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\ResGen.exe" documentserver.resx TXTextControl.DocumentServer.Properties.Resources.%1.resources
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\ResGen.exe" TXTextControl.Web.Server.Process.resx TXTextControl.Web.Server.Process.Properties.Resources.%1.resources
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\ResGen.exe" txdrawing.resx TXTextControl.Drawing.TXDrawing.%1.resources
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\ResGen.exe" txbarcode.resx TXTextControl.Barcode.TXBarcodeCore.%1.resources
@echo generating satellite assemblies:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\al.exe" /out:txtextcontrol.resources.dll /v:32.0.2500.500 /keyf:txtextcontrol.public.snk /c:%1 /delay+ /embed:TXTextControl.TextControlCore.%1.resources
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\al.exe" /out:txdocumentserver.resources.dll /v:32.0.1800.500 /keyf:txtextcontrol.public.snk /c:%1 /delay+ /embed:TXTextControl.DocumentServer.Properties.Resources.%1.resources
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\al.exe" /out:txtextcontrol.web.server.process.resources.dll /v:32.0.1200.500 /keyf:txtextcontrol.public.snk /c:%1 /delay+ /embed:TXTextControl.Web.Server.Process.Properties.Resources.%1.resources
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\al.exe" /out:txdrawing.resources.dll /v:32.0.800.500 /keyf:txtextcontrol.public.snk /c:%1 /delay+ /embed:TXTextControl.Drawing.TXDrawing.%1.resources
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\al.exe" /out:txbarcode.resources.dll /v:32.0.800.500 /keyf:txtextcontrol.public.snk /c:%1 /delay+ /embed:TXTextControl.Barcode.TXBarcodeCore.%1.resources
@echo turning off verification for the assemblies:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\sn.exe" -Vr txtextcontrol.resources.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\sn.exe" -Vr txdocumentserver.resources.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\sn.exe" -Vr txtextcontrol.web.server.process.resources.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\sn.exe" -Vr txdrawing.resources.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\sn.exe" -Vr txbarcode.resources.dll
@echo.
@echo satellite assemblies successfully generated.
@goto end
:error
buildres es
:end
```

Next step was to open the terminal with system admin rights and headed inside the subdirectory where the `buildres.bat` is located.

I executed the buildres.bat file on the terminal and then I got the `.resources.dll` files that are needed in order to import to my .NET Core app.

I created a subdirectory called `/es` inside my web application and imported these lines into my `.csproj` file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <RootNamespace>tx_aspnet_core_editor</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateSatelliteAssembliesForCore>true</GenerateSatelliteAssembliesForCore>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="TXTextControl.Web" Version="32.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="es\" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="es\txbarcode.resources.dll">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="es\txdocumentserver.resources.dll">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="es\txdrawing.resources.dll">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="es\txtextcontrol.resources.dll">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="es\txtextcontrol.web.server.process.resources.dll">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

It has worked like a charm.